# QSortFilterProxyModel and the slot setFilterFixedString

Tags: c++, qt

I currently have a search button and I would like to search a specific column of my model.Thus I just want the matching rows to be displayed in my tableview.
I have attached a QSortFilterProxyModel* object as a source to the table view and have set a QStandardItemModel* as its source. Then with my search button I made the following connection

```
QObject::connect(ui.lineEditSearch,SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)),proxyModelFilter,SLOT(setFilterFixedString(QString)));
```

Now I was under the impression that upon typing the relevant rows will be returned. Then I realized that I havent specified as to which columns I want the filter proxy model to search.
I understand that I could implement a class that inherits from QSortFilterProxyModel and re implement its filterAcceptsRow. I wanted to know if there was a way for me to avoid creating a class that inherits from QSortFilterProxyModel and simply use the QSortFilterProxyModel class only to tell which columns to search on when the Slot setFilterFixedString is called ?

Comment: `filterKeyColumn` allows you to search a single column, or all (-1)  (http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/qsortfilterproxymodel.html#filterKeyColumn-prop) Is that what you need, or do you need multiple but not all columns? Then you have to subclass, I think.

Comment: I just need to search one column and if that keyword is found then display the matching rows

Comment: That did the trick could you put that as the answer.So i could mark it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The column to filter by can be set via [QSortFilterProxyModel::filterKeyColumn](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/qsortfilterproxymodel.html#filterKeyColumn-prop).
It allows to specify a single column, or all of them (-1, the default).

Alternatively, one can define a custom filter role returning a concatenation of all string to search for, and set it via [setFilterRole()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/qsortfilterproxymodel.html#filterRole-prop).